# When does this equality hold for a continuous curve?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

Given a unit length continuous curve $\vec{r}(t), t \in [0,1]$ and $s \in (0,1)$, is it always possible to find some $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that the arc length from $t=t_0$ to $t=t_0+s$ equals to $s$ exactly?

When $s=\frac{1}{n}, n=2,3,...$ I can prove such $t_0$ exists, and when $s\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$ such $t_0$ may not exist (with a counterexample). Then what if $s\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$? I still couldn't find a clue to tell anything after trying to give a counterexample...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\vec r$ is rectifiable? Because if not, the arc length might not be defined.

Comment: @JackLee Right, it's rectifiable. Thanks:)